# How to best index this join query

Tags: mysql

Scenario: I have a form that auto suggests text as a user types, using an AJAX call to the backend. The call is made and the query is ran on every single character typed into the form input field. The query is looking for either a retail location name, retail location city, or a state (located in another table, joined by stated id)

Tables: (there are more fields in these tables but for the sake of brevity ...)

```
bbl_locations
    id
    name
    city
    state_id

bbl_states
    id
    name
```

bbl_location index:

```
| Table         | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| bbl_locations |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | id          | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| bbl_locations |          0 | name     |            1 | name        | A         |           1 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
```

bbl_states index:

```
| Table      | Non_unique | Key_name     | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| bbl_states |          0 | PRIMARY      |            1 | id           | A         |          54 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| bbl_states |          0 | abbreviation |            1 | abbreviation | A         |          54 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| bbl_states |          0 | name         |            1 | name         | A         |          54 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| bbl_states |          1 | country_id   |            1 | country_id   | A         |          54 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
```

Query: (searching for retailers in Missouri - remember, it would actually run as soon as i type 'M')

```
SELECT l.id
     , l.name
     , l.division 
  FROM bbl_locations l
  JOIN bbl_states s
    ON l.state_id = s.id 
 WHERE l.name LIKE '%missouri%' 
    OR l.city LIKE '%missouri%' 
    OR s.name LIKE '%missouri%'
```

Query Explain:

```
| id | select_type | table         | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                             | rows | Extra       |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | bbl_locations | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                            | 1    |             |
| 1  | SIMPLE      | bbl_states    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 2       | database.bbl_locations.state_id | 1    | Using where |
```

My Question: What can I do to improve speed on this query (currently executing around: 0.26)? Is there a better way to index or perform the above query?

Bonus question: Assuming I'm using a PDO abstraction layer, escaping input, and binding the values, does anyone see security issues with this query?

Anyhow, assuming multiple people will be accessing this search at the same time and typing in any possible combination of characters, I can see this becoming really slow and resource intensive and would like to mitigate that as best as possible. Thank you!!!

**[UPDATE]**
Per the comments below, I've updated the query to the following:

```
SELECT l.id
     , l.name
     , l.division 
  FROM bbl_locations l
  LEFT JOIN bbl_states s
    ON l.state_id = s.id 
 WHERE l.name LIKE 'missouri%' 
    OR l.city LIKE 'missouri%' 
    OR s.name LIKE 'missouri%'
```

The data set for states is small and even smaller for retailers right now so I don't really notice any difference, and the execution times are hovering around the same number as before. In EXPLAIN, it show an additional index being used. Fingers crossed. **Thank You** to everyone for your help, I truly appreciate it and if I could award you points I would do so.

If there is anything else I can do to improve the speed or security of this query, I'd greatly appreciate your advice. Thank you again!!!

Comment: No matter what index you set there, the `LIKE` search using both pre and postfix wildcards forces MySQL to do a full table scan - in your case, it will completely scan `locations` and `states` tables. Answer is - you cannot optimize it via indexes, if that query remains the same. The searches using MySQL (or similar) for the purpose of fast autocomplete are done by implementing a trie structure and sufficiently fast hardware.

Comment: I'm not married to this query, in fact it returns no results if the retailer doesn't set their state (though I require it - some circumstances may allow them to bypass). With that being said, if there is a better way to query the results, I'm open to suggestions. So far, that is the only query I've ran that gave me the results I was expecting.

Comment: (it's just the 'pre-' bit that's the performance killer)

Comment: Assuming you're talking about the '%" before Missouri, I saw that in another SO post and removed it after I posted this question. The execution times are still roughly the same, though I agree, I don't even need it there.

Comment: It makes a huge difference! Without a wildcard at the beginning you *can* make good use of indexes!

Comment: So EXPLAIN shows an additional key added to possible_keys. Now since I can make additional use of indexes, how would I go about better indexing for this query?

Comment: @jmgibson To get stores with no reference to `state` do a `LEFT JOIN`. This returns all entries of `bbl_locations` with `state_id = NULL`.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann that does seem to have solved that problem, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a full text index on `name` and `city` and use MATCH AGAINST in your query, but it's a bit of an overkill.

Comment: I am running InnoDB tables on 5.5.40-MariaDB; Not sure it is supported. Full-text searching isn't supported on MySQL till 5.6, not sure if same as what you're talking about.